# Crashed 3TB WD External HDD

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a 3TB external HDD that used to site on my desk; my dog caught the cable and it came crashing to the floor. I'm looking for suggestions on data recovery. I do accept that data recovery may not be possible. After the incident the drive did run for an hour or so before it failed. I have tried the following so far to no avail: I have attempted mounting it inside my workstation; it is a SATA drive. I have attempted swapping the internal HDD into another similar WD external HDD and nothing happened. Ultimately it doesn't register at all; I'm not able to get it to even be recognized. When I plug in the external drive it does not make any funny sounds; it does power up and the HDD does spin briefly before stopping.

I have attempted to use Recuva, a data recovery application that is free but  it will not be of help as it can't see the drive. A coworker suggested DD on linux and I found a Windows version however it also can't see the drive; the DD for Windows btw is here:
http://aeroquartet.com/movierepair/dd%20for%20windows

Comment: If it's not even detected now and the data's worth a lot to you it's time to contact the professionals. Here's a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/366540/harddrive-fell-caught-in-mid-air-wont-spin-up) BTW.

Comment: Thanks for this info; I'm trying two of the suggestions from that article now.

Comment: If the drive spins up that's a good sign but at this stage doing little as possible yourself is best most recovery software is the same if one didn't help there is very little you can do call the professionals